# upload file types according to radio button selections

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a html page, in which I am using two radio buttons say A and B,(A will be checked as default)

required solutiuon : when a user selects on A button

they should allowed to upload only .csv and .txt files, if they select another file, it should throw a message

Also, if they select radio button 'B' , they should allowed only to upload .config files

I have tried this much far :

```
   <div class="form-group">

     <label class="col col-md-2 control-label"><span class="widget-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-file txt-color-black"></i>Type of File </label>
       <div class="col-md-2">
       <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" class="selectfileclass" name="file" id="file_a" value="csv,txt" 
      checked/>File_A<br />

     </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" class="selectfileclass" name="file" id="config" value="config" 
       />Config<br />
     </label>
    
    
  <br>
  <br>
    </div>
  
    </div>
  </form>

 <span class="btn"><input type="file" class="selectfileclass" id="ImportFile" 
 accept=".csv,.txt" data-bind="event: { change: $root.Browse }"/></span>
 <script>
$('.selectfileclass').change(function() {
$('#ImportFile').attr("accept", "." + $(this).val())
})
</script>
```

still stuck, where I am missing,

any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put a dot before `"csv,txt"` it becomes `".csv,txt"` which is not a comma separated list of [unique file type specifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#unique_file_type_specifiers).

Perhaps the simplest solution is to put the file specifier list in radio button attribute values, and don't process them further when changing the `accept` attribute value of the file input.

```
<input type="radio" class="selectfileclass" name="file" id="file_a" value=".csv,.txt" checked>
 ...
<input type="radio" class="selectfileclass" name="file" id="config" value=".config">
 ...
 ...
    $('#ImportFile').attr("accept", $(this).val())
```

A possible enhancement to ensure the uploaded radio button `file` value matches the type of the files selected would be to *clear the file input value* when the radio buttons are changed:

```
   $('#ImportFile').val(""); // before setting
   $('#ImportFile').attr("accept", $(this).val())
```